# How to set page jumps to work on all browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, safari, page-jump

I have recently completed a Shopify website and all works fine. I am now going through the different browsers to make sure works fine for everyone and I have noticed a few issues regarding page jumps that I have within my site.

For example on the following page:

https://prontaprint247.com/pages/price-list

the page jumps work fine and go to the correct sections that I need in Firefox but when I do the same in Safari and Chrome, the jumps work but there are taking me to the wrong section and I am not sure what I need to do to fix this as not sure if its a browser issue or what.

Would really appreciate it if somebody could advise, as I have checked the tags and they all appear correctly for each page jump so a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the following post and Per I was able to resolve the issues with the anchor links (page jumps) now this works the same in all browsers...

http://www.coffeecup.com/forums/designer/anchor-links-in-google-chrome/?page=2

Thought I would post this for anyone else who runs into this issue.